# Responsive matching height of grid element parts

Tags: javascript, css, grid, alignment

I build a grid where the grid elements have an image, a title, a short text and a button. Here is an example.
[image]

As you can see, the images have bit of different height, also some titles and text are shorter/longer.
I'm looking for a CSS/Vanilla JS solution which aligns the height of the images/titles/etc responsively for the row.

The result should be something like this:
[image]

So every image wrapper has the same height, the titles starts on the same position, the buttons are also aligned, etc.

This can't be CSS min-height, because the data source is dynamic and I don't know what I'll get.
It must be responsive, work with 2/3/4/5 elements in a row.
Also tried masonry, but didn't like it.

I tried to dig a bit and was able to match the height of the cards but not the parts of the cards.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: the easiest way is to include a container that wraps the image and gives it a specific height while using `object-fit` to handle the image to the container size.  The rest should solve itself if all images have the same height.

Comment: each card (image, title, button) inside your outer grid can be a grid. This grid card has 1 column, 3 rows. First row with image let say 50% height. Last row for the button, let say 5%. So you'll have something like grid-template-rows: 50% 1fr 5%.

Comment: "*[Could] you provide a minimum reproducible example in a snippet?*" - I'd ask the same of you, can you share your current HTML, and CSS, so that we all have a common base to work from that doesn't require each of us to create the entirety of your images?